# Best way for Search NSArray1 for value matching element in NSArray2

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsarray

I'm totally new to iOS development.

I have a `NSArray1(parent array)` of elements something like this :

```
( (name1,url-x,logo-x), (name2,url2,logo2),(name3,url-y, logo-y) )
```

and `NSArray2(child array)` of elements something like this:

```
( (name1,des1,time1), (name1,des2,time2), (name1,des3, time3), (name2,des4,time4), (name2,des5,time5), (name2, des6,time6), (name3,des7,time7), (name3,des8,time8), (name3, des9,time9) )
```

I want to put all the relative `NSArray2(child array)` elements in to `NSArry1(Parent array)` like this:

```
( (name1,url-x,logo-x,des1,time1,des2,time2,des3, time3), (name2, url2, logo2, des4, time4, des5, time5, des6, time6),  ... )
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: You should really switch to `NSDictionary` instead of using arrays: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/

Comment: Did you consider to use objects instead of this a bit weird solution? Then keep the objects in the array. I don't like `NSDictionary` way mentioned above, as objects are more straightforward, easy to read and maintain later.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your code. It probably would be better to use objects instead of nested arrays.

Example:

```
@interface Object1 : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray <Object2 *> *objects2; // if you use Xcode 7
// @property (nonatomic) NSArray *objects2; // if you use earlier Xcode // array of Object2
@end

@implementation Object1
@end
```

And another class:

```
@interface Object2 : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger des;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate time;
@end

@implementation Object2
@end
```

This way you can keep as many des/time pairs for given name, also this is more readable by other developers and surely will lead to fewer errors, crashes and bugs.

Later in code you just keep an array of `Object1`.